# KendoUI mobile doesn't work on an actual mobile when viewed in browser (without phonegap)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Using KendoUI mobile. I'm looking for help on what I'm doing wrong here. I've created my app, looks great on a desktop, but actually uploading it then viewing it on a mobile browser doesn't work. Either blank or unstyled HTML is shown.

For example, the example files that are packaged in the download zip file when uploaded to a server and viewed in the phones normal browser (not in an app via phonegap/cordova) just present plain html.

Can anyone point out what glaring error I'm making, or is it just the case that it will only work with phonegap/cordova?

thanks

Comment: We would need to see some code. You can use jsbin.com to create a sample which reproduces your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The KendoUI Mobile example that is provided with the zip download doesn't appear to work in an actual browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139493/the-kendoui-mobile-example-that-is-provided-with-the-zip-download-doesnt-appear)