# The KendoUI Mobile example that is provided with the zip download doesn't appear to work in an actual browser

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

As stated in title, not my own project nor the actual demo/example provided with KendoUI Mobile seems to work in an actual mobile browser. It works fine in FF/Chrome etc, but when I upload it to my server, it either doesn't display, or just shows unstyled HTML.

I have placed the Kendo example files on a server http://prototype94.com/mobile/listview/index.html view - this on your phones browser and you will see it doesn't work.

If the Cordova/PhoneGap is to create some wrapper app that utilises the phone's own web browser, but the phones own web browser doesn't display the site/page correctly, then how is KendoUI supposed to work

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: KendoUI is a commercial product, so you will probably get an answer to your question through their support channels.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the page source, the examples use relative paths to load jQuery and Kendo UI Mobile scripts and styles which are located in the /styles and /js root subfolders. When you create your own page and upload it somewhere, you will need to relocate these resources, so that the page can find and load them (currently it doesn't).